# How can I create dynamic imports in Freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

I want create dynamics imports in freemarket based in a previous list I have created...

```
<#if filesList??>
    <#list filesList as specificFile>
        <#import ${specificFile} + ".ftlh" as ${specificFile}>
    </#list>
<#else>
    NO FILES
</#if>
```

Always giving me an error... How can I use it?

Thank you

Comment: Always giving me error  ? what error?

Comment: It doesn't like (or allow) add ${var} inside import annotation

Comment: Change this line from   `<#import ${specificFile} + ".ftlh" as ${specificFile}>` To  `<#import specificFile + ".ftlh" as specificFile>`

Comment: I want to use "specificFile" file given from dataset as variable such ${specificFile}
This line...
`<#import specificFile + ".ftlh" as specificFile>` use specificFile as name